# CORS policy Delphi Rest Full

Tags: angular, restful, delphi-10

Estou criando um server Delphi Rest Full para ser acessado com front-end Angular, consigo aplicar o POST, PUT e GET porém na tentativa de  executar um DELETE recebo o erro do CORS implementei tratamento conforme varios exemplos da internet mas sem sucesso. como devo proceder para resolver o DELETE??

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/datasnap/rest/apiPais/Pais/2' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
 // Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');

  Response.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']      := '*';
  Response.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] := 'true';
  Response.CustomHeaders.Values['Access-Control-Allow-Methods']     := 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';

  if Trim(Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers')) <> '' then
  begin
    Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
    Handled := True;
  end;

  if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
    FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
end;
```

Comment: Qual é o HTTP status do pre-flight? Ele deve ser 200.

Comment: Vc conseguiu resolver @Ailton

Comment: Amigo... tentei tudo que foi literatura a respeito, segui exemplos mas não funciona... tentei achar seu e-mail para um PVT mas sem sucesso... se puder me socorrer agradeço  (ps - nem sei se posso fazer este tipo de pedido por aqui, mas se puder segue meu email ailtonbrc@hotmail.com)

Comment: Adicione a pergunta os resultado da requisicao do DELETE.

Comment: Pelo erro, parece que o problema é que o teu servidor não tá respondendo o preflight com um 200...

Comment: então esta resposta que não sei implementar... consegui resolver de tudo menos dele